# Detect event when the user picks up phone without dialing

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I am currently linking asterisk to a web application, I am able, via AMI telnet connection, to detect when the line is ringing, when the user is dialing, when he hangs up.

I really would like to know when he picks up the phone but do not compose/dial anything, just taking the phone in his hand.
In telnet on AMI, nothing happens until he really dials something.

Can you help me detecting this event please ?

Comment: If the connection is SIP, not sure you're going to get that level of information. I don't think the phone opens a connection and sends a SIP request until the number is dialed.

Comment: Yes it is SIP, if there is another mode allowing that between Cisco SPA5xx phone and asterisk, I would change. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Phone do nothing when you pickup it, unless it have "Hot-line" feature.

So asterisk even never know you do that.

You need find ATA or Phone with Hot-line and enable that. If so, phone will call hot-line number when you pickup it.

Comment: Thank you arheops for the answer, I cannot change the Cisco phones, it is really a pity that asterisk cannot detect this, it would have been top success for my app :(

Comment: @Mykeul FYI, it's not really the phone's fault. It's how SIP works; no request is made to the server until the call is dialed.

Comment: Yes Lynn I understood thanks to your earlier message, and if I can use another protocol to get this working, I would.

Comment: SPA*** cisco phones(before was sipura) fully support hotline. Non of protocol will inform server. Unless hotline used

Comment: For enable you have add into directory line like this: "S0<:1002@ip_address_of_server:5060>". Note, after that all calls will be done via hotline mode.